# How to change connection string for each database in each server

Tags: powershell, azure-analysis-services

Say i have 2 servers server 1 and server 2.

In each server there are x databases, each having a connection to a global database.

> server1 has database1, datatabse2, database3.
>
> server2 has database4, database5

We would have 2 files, one file containing the servers, and another containing the "databases"

then the loop would be:

```
Import-Module SqlServer 

foreach ($server in $servers_file)
{
    $Analysis_Server = New-Object Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Server  
    $Analysis_Server.connect("$server") 

    foreach ($database in $databases_file)
    {
        $database = $Analysis_Server.Databases.FindByName($database)

        ####### Setting connection property for $database #######

        $database.DataSources[0].ConnectionString = "UserId=…;Password=…."
    }

}
```

the problem here is this loop does not consider where a database belongs for the server.

for example, if i have the database file as:

> database1
>
> database2
>
> database3
>
> database4
>
> database5

how can i make this loop know that it has to exit the inner loop when database1-3 has finished from server1, and now you have to move on to the outerloop to connect to server2 for databases4 and 5.

ConnectionInfo class: https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/dotnet/api/microsoft.analysisservices.connectioninfo?view=sqlserver-2016

Comment: Can you have a separate database file for each server?

Comment: @zdan...I guess...but then the file name would have to be the server name right? I wouldnt know how to pass the filename though as server variable...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seeing your last comment on wanting to use a csv file to populate the Hashtable, you can do this:

Suppose your CSV looks like this

```
"Server","Database"
"server1","database1"
"server2","database4"
"server1","database2"
"server1","database3"
"server2","database5"
```

You can then read it in using `Import-Csv` and create a hash from it like this

```
$h = @{}
Import-Csv '<PATH_TO_THE_CSV_FILE>' | Group-Object Server | ForEach-Object {
    $db = @()
    foreach ($item in $_.Group) {
        $db += $item.Database 
    }
    $h += @{$($_.Name) = $db}
}
```

Depending on your version of PowerShell (I think you need at least 5.1 for this), you can simplify the previous by doing:

```
$h = @{}
Import-Csv 'D:\Code\PowerShell\StackOverflow\Databases.csv' | Group-Object Server | ForEach-Object {
    $h += @{$($_.Name) = $_.Group.Database}
}
```

Next you can use the loop as described by thom schumacher:

```
foreach($server in $h.Keys){ 
   $Analysis_Server = New-Object Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Server  
   $Analysis_Server.connect("$server") 
   foreach($db in $h[$server]) {
      write-output "$server - has db $db"
      $database = $Analysis_Server.Databases.FindByName($db)

      ####### Setting connection property for $database #######

      $database.DataSources[0].ConnectionString = "UserId=…;Password=…."

    }
}
```

**Edit**

From your comment I gather your csv file looks like this:

```
"Server","Database"
"server1", "database1, database2, database3"
"server2","database4, database5"
```

In that case, you can read it into a Hashtable like this:

```
$h = @{}
Import-Csv '<PATH_TO_THE_CSV_FILE>' | ForEach-Object {
    $h += @{$($_.Server) = ($_.Database -split '\s*,\s*') }
}
```

If your CSV file does **not** have headers like above, user the `-Header` switch on the `Import-Csv` cmdlet to give the columns a name we can work with like this:

```
    Import-Csv '<PATH_TO_THE_CSV_FILE>' -Header 'Server','Database'
```

Comment: This is fantastic! Btw, what if my csv looks like this: ”server1”, ”database1, database2, database3” next line ”server2”,”database4, database5”...etc...can you give me an example2 (keep the one you have just add another example how the import-csv can be changed to accommodate that kind of input)

Comment: @Cataster I have added code to deal with that csv layout to the answer

Comment: thanks so much! btw, i could swear theer was an edit about with space or no space...but im guessing you made the case take care of both using these switches: '\s*,\s*, right?

Comment: also, i think you meant to pass $db instead of database here: Databases.FindByName($db)

Comment: btw i am receiving some connection error. if you know a solution to this, here is a thread i created: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53013069/why-cant-i-set-the-connection-string

Comment: @Cataster Fixed the typo in `FindByName($db)` and yes, I did have a slightly different version at first because suddenly I realized you _can_ have spaces in the database names. That version worked, but later I decided to use `'\s*,\s*'` in the split to take care of both situations.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you make a hashtable where you assign the Database values to each server.

```
$h=@{'server1'=( 'database1','database2','database3');'server2'=( 'database4','database5')}
```

Then your loop becomes:

```
foreach($key in $h.keys){ 
   $Analysis_Server = New-Object Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Server  
   $Analysis_Server.connect("$key") 
   foreach($value in $h[$key])
    {
      write-output "$key - has db $value"
      $database = $Analysis_Server.Databases.FindByName($database)

      ####### Setting connection property for $database #######

      $database.DataSources[0].ConnectionString = "UserId=…;Password=…."

    }
}
```

Comment: this site has a really good writeup on powershell hash tables https://kevinmarquette.github.io/2016-11-06-powershell-hashtable-everything-you-wanted-to-know-about/

Comment: Good alternative, but the issue is the hash table cant be hardcoded like that. How can it be built dynamically ? What if I had n servers and x databases...I guess the other way is using a csv file equivalent

Comment: You can build a hash table from a file

Comment: I think I want to use a csv file. I read kevin's blog, he only has an export-csv command for hashtable, I would need an import command to import the csv file and populate the hashtable with server corresponding to databases